# How to get current DNS settings if I do not have access to admin panel?

Tags: domain-name-system

There is a site, it needs to move to another server. It's copied there, works well.
Now I need to change my A-record. And then I learn that for some reasons we do not have access to NS admin end.

We have another DNS and we CAN switch domain to it, but we don't know all the settings, there was much of them (MX, CNAME, etc.) so I can't just create A-record and let it go.
Is there a way to read current settings of the NS remotely? I mean, I can get A-record (IP where the domain is pointing at), so maybe I can get all (or at least some) others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) to get all of the relevant DNS information pointing at a specific host. You need to know what the authoritative name server for that hostname is, and run: `dig @ns.example.com example.com ANY`.

Replace `ns.example.com` with the old nameserver and `example.com` with the hostname you're interested in.

(`dig` is part of the `bind` package, usually the clients are in a separate package, e.g. http://packages.debian.org/sid/dnsutils)

#### Example Output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @ns1.yahoo.com yahoo.com ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26934
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 14, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 7
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yahoo.com.         IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.com.      1800    IN  SOA ns1.yahoo.com. hostmaster.yahoo-inc.com. 2012042707 3600 300 1814400 600
yahoo.com.      3600    IN  A   209.191.122.70
yahoo.com.      3600    IN  A   72.30.38.140
yahoo.com.      3600    IN  A   98.139.183.24
yahoo.com.      1800    IN  MX  1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com.      1800    IN  MX  1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com.      1800    IN  MX  1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns3.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns1.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns2.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns6.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns4.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns5.yahoo.com.
yahoo.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns8.yahoo.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   68.180.131.16
ns2.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   68.142.255.16
ns3.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   121.101.152.99
ns4.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   68.142.196.63
ns5.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   119.160.247.124
ns6.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   202.43.223.170
ns8.yahoo.com.      172800  IN  A   202.165.104.22

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 68.180.131.16#53(68.180.131.16)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 28 19:27:50 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 449
```

Answer (score 1):

can you at least download the zone files? that is actually all you need. if you cannot even do that, you would have to use dig or another client to go through all the records that you know to find information, that would be painful.